# How to rename a column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to rename the column from a table.
I have tried:

- `EXEC sp_rename`
- `alter table`
- `alter table change`

Also I do not want to add one more column and assign the data of old column to new and drop old column.

How can I do it ?

Comment: When you tried, what error you got?

Comment: Are you not able to open object explorer in Management studio and edit the name of column?

Comment: @mhn i need some script or query, requirenets doesnt allow to use object explorer.

Comment: Why do you think `sp_rename` is NOT working?

Comment: @user3817378 so why is it not working for you ? Are you getting an error ? Did you forget to refresh your table ? It works for most other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a old version of mssql so does not support above solutions but when i tried like this it works

```
EXEC sys.sp_rename 'fg.TABLE NAME.OLD_COLUMN_NAME','NEW_COLUMN_NAME','COLUMN';
```

anyway thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_rename as follows :

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'table_name.old_name', 'NEWNAME', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Command

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Table_Name.CololdName', 'ColNewName' , 'COLUMN'
```

it is working perfectly for me